# How to persist a changes in a DBML (Stored Procedure)

Tags: linq-to-sql

i am using stored procedure and if i add/remove parameters (in the sproc) than when i come to see in dbml than i dont see any changes so what i am doing currently is remove the sproc and added back to dbml designer.

is this a normal behaviour of linqtosql?

in the future if i end-up modify the sproc for some reason do i need to end-up updating dbml also ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of generating Linq To SQL classes from a database, neither of which offers round-trip coding or live update. If you change your database, including sprocs, then you'll need to regenerate your Linq to SQL classes.

Comment: so i guess i have only option is to go with ADO.NET

Comment: Even in ADO.NET you are going to have to change your code if the sproc return changes. Nothing to be gained, regenerating the Linq to SQL classes isn't painful.